# Unable to align radio buttons and their labels in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Below is a snippet of the appearance of current page.

[Radio buttons and their labels not in single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXgZJ.png)

Below is the piece of code is being used. (JSP)

```html
<div class="leftFormComp" style="width: 100%;">
  <label class="inputLabel" for="ext-comp-1045">
   <span class="required">*</span><fmt:message key="registration.agreement"/>
  </label>

  <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1045" class="x-form-element" style="padding-left: 8px;">
   <div id="ext-comp-1045" class=" x-form-checklist" style="width: 344px; height: auto;">

    <div class="x-form-cb-li x-form-cb-li-h" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
      <input id="termsAgree-Y" class="x-form-field" type="radio" value="Y" name="termsAgree"> <label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-Y"><fmt:message key="registration.yes"/></label>
    </div>

    <div class="x-form-cb-li x-form-cb-li-h">
      <input id="termsAgree-N" class="x-form-field" type="radio" value="N" name="termsAgree"> <label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-N"><fmt:message key="registration.no"/></label>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried using inline styling like

```
display: inline!important;
```

with input and label tags but nothing is working.

While checking in Chrome Developer mode, I came across an extra attribute that was getting appended in the input tags of both the radio buttons and I am unable to figure out from where it is coming.

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}
```

Can someone please suggest way to override all existing stylings that are getting implemented on this element, so as to bring the radio buttons and their labels in one line. I am new to front-end part, so please help me out. Also, help me find the origin of this styling (Can it be found using Chrome Developer tool)

Comment: Which element are you inspecting that is getting the display:block assignment? What CSS selector did you put display:inline!important on? Is all your CSS and JavaScript custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to fix this would be to simply add "float: left" to the radio buttons.

```
<input style="float:left" id="termsAgree-N" class="x-form-field" type="radio" value="N" name="termsAgree"> 
<label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-N"><fmt:message key="registration.no"/></label>
```

This means you don't need to worry about changing to `display:inline-block`. This snippet demonstrates that it works even when the radio buttons are set to `display:block`.

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" style="display:block;" />
  <label>without float:left</label>
</div><br/>

</br/>
<div>
  <input type="radio" style="display:block; float:left" />
  <label>with float:left</label>
</div>
```

This is a picture of before and after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @DeltaMarine101. It is working fine now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just write after fmt

```
<label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-Y">
      <fmt:message key="registration.yes" />Yes
</label>
```

i think it will work.

Comment: fmt:message key="registration.yes"--> This is already bringing the Yes value from properties file. Thanks for your help. It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You did that wrong. You missed the right name.

change it into `display:inline-block;`

In the example below I used it onto the `div`'s. But this css will work on every element you want.

```css
div{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="leftFormComp" style="width: 100%;">
  <label class="inputLabel" for="ext-comp-1045">
   <span class="required">* Subject</span><fmt:message key="registration.agreement"/>
  </label>

  <div id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1045" class="x-form-element" style="padding-left: 8px;">
   <div id="ext-comp-1045" class=" x-form-checklist" style="width: 344px; height: auto;">

    <div class="x-form-cb-li x-form-cb-li-h" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
      <input id="termsAgree-Y" class="x-form-field" type="radio" value="Y" name="termsAgree"> <label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-Y"><fmt:message key="registration.yes"/>Yes</label>
    </div>

    <div class="x-form-cb-li x-form-cb-li-h">
      <input id="termsAgree-N" class="x-form-field" type="radio" value="N" name="termsAgree"> <label class="x-form-cb-label" for="termsAgree-N"><fmt:message key="registration.no"/>No</label>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: No, this did not work. But DeltaMarine101's solution worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anytime.There are multiple ways to do the same thing. But it usually depends on the system you run it on and compatibility to check what does and doesn't work. Good luck with your project!